# Esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total amount of goats Yaakov sent to Esav.

The total amount of sheep Yaakov sent to Esav.

(Vayishlach 32:15)

Answer (score 2):

The Egyptian exile was foretold at the Bris Bein Habesarim 220 years before it happened. (The BBH took place when Avraham was 70 years old, in the year 2018 since Creation; Yaakov and his family descended to Egypt in 2238.)

Also, Chasam Sofer [states](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4930&pgnum=63) (paragraph beginning או שי"ל) that the Egyptian exile should by rights have lasted for 220 years, since Yosef's ten brothers (by their selling him) each caused Yaakov 22 years of misery. However, Hashem kindly deducted a year for each of them, for the fact that they themselves had to experience the distress of dying outside Eretz Yisrael.

Comment: http://www.learningtorah.org/DvarTorah/ViewDvarTorah.aspx?dtID=743

Answer (score 1):

עזרא: ח. כ.
ומן הנתינים שנתן דויד והשרים לעבדת הלוים נתינים **מאתים ועשרים** כלם נקבו בשמות

דברי הימים א: טו. ו.
לבני מררי עשיה השר ואחיו **מאתים ועשרים**